# Why does my combobox not display anything?

Tags: html, select, bootstrap-4

I'm using a `combobox` (select) to display countries. I doing this using Bootstrap.

This is the code

```
<select class="form-control form-control-user" id="inputCountry" name="country" placeholder="Country">
  <option value="NL">Netherlands</option>
  <option value="BE">Belgium</option>
  <option value="LX">Luxembourg</option>
  <option value="GR">Greece</option>
  <option value="NO">Norway</option>
</select>
```

When I go to my browser, my `combobox` is empty. When I click it I can see the entries. When I select an entry, nothing shows in the `combobox`. When I try to echo the value of the `combobox`, I get the value, so it's a visual issue.

removing 1 of the classes (form-control or form-control-use) will fix this, but the design I want gets lost.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Have you linked the combobox css and js files properly?

Answer (score -1):

I have tried your code block and it was working without a problem.

This is the JSFiddle link which I have done some modificatoins:

https://jsfiddle.net/mw5904uf/

Here, I have created `form-control-user` css class. I am not sure that this is what you want. Anyhow make sure you have linked css and js files correctly as Charlene said.

In addition, since your placeholder didn't work, I have modified that by adding another option.

Comment: i didnt vote this down. im using bootstrap, i think the issue in there